# Exclude data that does not have parent in hierarchical schema

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I work on a project where we have several tables storing information telling if an entity can have some permissions. Some of these permissions have hierarchical relations (I cannot write in a file if I cannot read in this file, the permission "write_file" would be a child of "read_file" for example). This is how it works, and how it worked for years, I cannot touch that.

We probably still have ooold mysql versions, like mysql 4 :(

We have a table "aggregating" permissions, from different other tables, and after this aggregation, I have to filter out permissions not having their parents permissions, in a request that can potentially affect quite a lot of users.

I don't know how to filter out these permissions, it all :'(

```sql
CREATE TABLE permissions {
 id int not null,
 parentId int not null, -- can be 0, meaning this feature does not have parents
 name varchar
 -- etc
};

UPDATE aggregat_table at
  JOIN toto, titi, tutu -- some joins on other table
  INNER JOIN permissions p on p.id = toto.id OR p.id = titi.id OR p.id = tutu.id
  -- JOIN on permissions, but I can't figure out how, to filter out parentless permissions
  SET -- etc etc
```

Hierarchie is not deep, most of the time there is 3 level, maybe 4 sometime.

```
id;  parent_id;   name

1;   0;           "can_drink"
2;   0;           "can_walk"
3;   2;           "can_run"
5;   4;           "can_moonwalk"       # is child permission of 4, will be removed
8;   7;           "can_write_document" # is child permission of 7; which is child of 6, will be removed
7;   6;           "can_read_document"  # is child permission of 6, will be removed
```

If `permissions p` results in previous step, I would like to keep "can_drink", because it is a root permission, "can_walk", same reason, "can_run", because these *is* his parent in this set, I would like to get rid of "can_moonwalk", because there is not his parent in the set, and "can_write_document" and "can_read_document" have to disappear, too, because they depend on permission 6 (can_read_document has 6 as parent id, can_write_document has can_read_document as parent, so has 6 as grand parent)

The result would be :

```
id;  parent_id;   name

1;   0;           "can_drink" # is "root" permission, stayed
2;   0;           "can_walk"  # is "root" permission, stayed
3;   2;           "can_run"   # is child permission, parent is in the set, stayed
```

Speed matter, a lot.

Thanks for your help

Comment: My first thought, which you probably aren’t going to like, is that if this is “how it worked for years”, has this possibly been solved already by someone else? I’m building a custom and semi-similar permission system right now and I’d love to have that already built by someone else

Comment: Yes and no, this job is actually done by firing thousand of requests, and by delegating some of this logic php side, which causes performance issues.

Comment: You mentioned that there's a PHP element to this. Does it have to run as part of this process? Or the PHP element is distinct from the core question asked here?

Comment: It is currently highly coupled, but I really want to avoid to use php there, it would involve too much perf issues

Comment: What version of MySQL? this is vital information, MySQL v8 is way different to MySQL v5.7 etc. PLEASE always state the version somewhere in your question

Comment: We have some very old mysql versions, probably V4

Comment: What do ids 4 and 6 have?  What is the desired result?

Comment: MySQL 8.0 has CTEs, which allow arbitrarily deep trees; pre-8.0 has nothing (other than brute force) for handling trees.

Comment: Run`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ver%';`  If it is 4.0, there may be even more difficulties.  (4.1 thru 5.7 have similar _main_ features; then 8.0 has loads of big new features).

Comment: Can't use SHOW VARIABLES, the project is on hundred of different independant servers, some offline.... unfortunaly.

Comment: If this "tree" is spread across multiple servers, then the cost of connecting and querying the servers is the main performance problem, not SQL.  Furthermore, it cannot be handled by a single SQL statement unless you have Spider or FEDERATEDx.

Comment: `of different independant servers` , they are not related, we just have several different instances of our platforms

Answer (score 1):

(please don't use the old 'comma-join', use `JOIN..ON`)

(`INNER JOIN` == `JOIN`; I am too lazy to type INNER)

LEFT JOIN permissions AS p2  ON ...
...
WHERE p2 = 0

```
UPDATE aggregat_table at
    JOIN toto
    JOIN titi ON ...
    JOIN titu ON ...
    # some joins on other table
    JOIN permissions p
        ON  p.id = toto.id
         OR p.id = titi.id
         OR p.id = tutu.id
    WHERE ... [ see below ]
    SET ...
```

To skip update the row(s) without a parent:

```
    WHERE p.parentid != 0
```

To act on only the parentless row(s):

```
    WHERE p.parentid = 0
```

To skip update the row(s) without a GRANDparent:

```
    WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM permissions AS p2
                           WHERE p2.id = p.parentid
                             AND p2.parentid = 0 )
```

And be sure to have `PRIMARY KEY(id)` on `permissions`, if appropriate.  And if *may* be desirable to have `INDEX(parentid)`.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't see that question was understable this way. I'll try to rephrase. I don't want to filter on permissions that don't have parent in absolute, but I want to have permissions that are root permissions, or permissions that have their ancestors in permissions p (the set has to include parents and child)

Comment: Can the tree be arbitrarily deep?

Comment: It's a critical part, yes and no, actually it won't be more than 3 lvl, but we CAN update query if needed

Comment: For pre-8.0, it might be solved using the UNION of 3 SELECTs.  What should the resultset look like (for the example data)?

Comment: I've updated initial post, I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

***I am going to assume that the maximum depth of the tree is four.***

1. If the hierarchy is maximum *n* level deep, you can use *n - 1* left outer joins to find the *ultimate parent* of a node.
2. An orphan node, in your example, would be the one whose *ultimate parent* does not have parent_id = 0.

So you can simply do this:

```sql
select n0.*
from t      as n0
left join t as p1 on n0.parent_id = p1.id
left join t as p2 on p1.parent_id = p2.id
left join t as p3 on p2.parent_id = p3.id
where coalesce(p3.parent_id, p2.parent_id, p1.parent_id, n0.parent_id) = 0
-- note about coalesce:
-- the ultimate parent needs to be checked from right to left
```

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=715be39a1b3b0a7fcb47eb53482a0188)